# question on kotlin coroutines with webclient

Tags: kotlin, spring-webclient

I am new to kotlin. I have written a function that processes two webclient calls in parallel and then aggregates the result. the point is that it is written in a java style (below the code)

```
@GetMapping("/personv1/{id}")
suspend fun getPerson1(@PathVariable id :Integer): Mono<Person> =
    Mono.zip(
        webClient.get().uri("/person/{id}", id).retrieve().bodyToMono(Person::class.java),
        webClient.get().uri("/person/{id}/domain", id).retrieve().bodyToMono(String::class.java)
    ) { person, domain -> Person(person.id, person.name, domain) }
```

I wanted to make the same code using coroutines following examples, but I am blocked at the very beginning. My idea was to declare two variables one of type Deferred of a Person and the other one Deferred of a String and then wait for them to merge the data but I am not able to declare any of the variables.

Here is the code I have started

```
@GetMapping("/personv2/{id}")
suspend fun getPerson2(@PathVariable id :Integer): Person = coroutineScope {
    val person: Deferred<Person> = async {
        webClient
            .get()
            .uri("/person/{id}", id)
            .retrieve()
            .awaitBody<Person>()
    }

}
```

But my IDE is telling me that my person val should be of type ServerResponse and not a Deferred of Person

Can someone help me on that ? what am I doing wrong?

thanks for your help

Comment: It looks right to me. Try replacing `async` with `this@coroutineScope.async` to see if you're calling some other `async` function.

Comment: it works!! Thanks a lot. Can you give me some explainations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `async` with `this@coroutineScope.async`.

There must be some other function in your scope called `async` that has a higher priority resolution than `CoroutineScope.async` inside your `coroutineScope` lambda. The `coroutineScope` lambda is passed a CoroutineScope as the receiver, so `this@coroutineScope.async` will clarify that you specifically mean to call `CoroutineScope.async` on the receiver of the lambda and not some other `async` function.

I'm not familiar with Spring so I don't have any guesses what the other `async` function is. You might be able to change your imports in this file such that `async` will resolve to `CoroutineScope.async` without you having to prefix it with `this@coroutineScope`. If you want to find out what other function it is resolving to, remove the prefix and Ctrl+Click the function name `async` and the IDE will take you to the source code for it.

Comment: indeed I had an async also coming from Spring. thanks a lot. I just removed it because it became useless and the code is now more readable